# A twice differentiable function such that $f''$ is continuous

Tags: derivatives

Let $f$ be a twice differentiable function such that $f''$ is continuous and $f''(x)\neq0$ for all $x\in \Bbb R$. Let $f(0)=1$, $f(1)=0$ and $f'(0)=0$. Prove that $f'(1)\leq -1$.

Comment: Do you know mean value theorem?

Comment: Does $f''$ need to be continuous in  this problem? It is not required i think as it is already Darboux. Please tell if i am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mean value theorem says $f(1)-f(0)=-1=f'(c)$ for some $0<c<1$. Since $f'(0)=0$, $f''$ must be negative somewhere in the interval. Since $f''(x)$ is never 0, $f'$ is decreasing on the interval. Thus
$$f'(1)\leq f'(c)=-1$$

Answer (score 2):

Because $f''$ has no roots and is continuous it follows from the intermediate value theorem that either $f'' > 0$ or $f'' < 0$. Thus $f'$ is either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing. By the mean value therom it follows that there exists some $\xi \in (0,1)$ with
$$
 f'(\xi) = \frac{f(1)-f(0)}{1-0} = f(1)-f(0) = -1.
$$
Because $f'(0) = 0$ it follows that $f'$ is strictly decreasing. Becaus $1 > \xi$ it follows that $f'(1) < f'(\xi) = -1$.

Comment: Does $f''$ need to be continuous in  this problem? It is not required i think as it is already Darboux. Please tell if i am wrong.

Comment: I am sadly not familiar with Darboux functions, but from what I find on Wikipedia does it right: We only need that from $f''(x) < 0$ and $f''(y) > 0$ for some $x \neq y$ it follows that $f''(c) = 0$ for some $c$. This seems to follow from Darboux's theorem.